# wro4j - build all groups using runtime solution

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, wro4j

I'm using wro4j with a maven + spring-mvc based web application. I have two different wro.properties file to configure the web app differently when in development mode vs deployment mode. wro4j is configured to run using the runtime solution. The setup is working fine so far.

What I want to be able to do now is that in deployment mode, all the wro4j groups should be built immediately on server start up (as opposed to on-first-request per wro resource). I haven't found a configuration option for this - is there one? If not, how can I go about making this happen?

(I know I can probably get similar result using compile mode for deployment, but given that I already have runtime mode set up I am wondering if I can piggy back on that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to create a custom [requestHandler](https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/RequestHandler) which would iterate through all the groups and would trigger processing. You would have to invoke that request handler during application startup.

If you would like to have this feature out of the box, feel free to open an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/issues/list).

Comment: I created a custom requestHandler following the wro4j examples. Got that part working - checked by requesting the wroAPI url manually. But how do I invoke the request handler during startup?

Comment: Use a ServletContextListener to get notified about application startup and invoke the url of your custom requestHandler.

Comment: How, in contextInitialized, can you "invoke" the requestHandler ?  Using an http client or kind of mocking an HttpServetRequest ?